# How to return all values in Sequelize after create

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I am working on a feature where the server creates an entry in the DB using Sequelize.create().

When this operation is fulfilled, we would like to return the whole list of objects (like .findAll) and send it back in the API response, with the newly added entry.

Which is the beck option?

Comment: after successful create you need to query to return all records.. if u dont want to fetch after create then u can also implement aftercreate hook to return all record.

Comment: If you mean `Model.create` it creates only one record and then it returns newly created record.

Comment: Yes, I solved it myself yesterday. Thanks for the help.